# Combining manifolds with different pressure

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I want to ask how can I calculate pressure in a horizontal pipeline (with "x [bar]?") in this situation a pipe is combining two manifolds with different pressures. In Manifold 2 the pressure is lower than in the Manifold 1. It is possible to determine, using analytical methods, the pressure which I'm looking for? Also, I want to calculate the flow rate and velocity in the horizontal pipe.
[image]

Comment: you use a pipe flow calculator based on the pressure difference, or the equations and factors you'd find in an engineering book.

Comment: could you send me any materials with equations about which you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy, because minor loss coefficients for T-junctions are generally dependent on ratio of flowrates in the branches, so you cannot calculate it directly. As for the coefficients, you may look into [Idelchik's Handbook of Hydraulic Resistance](https://www.nrc.gov/docs/ML1220/ML12209A041.pdf) or [Crane's Technical Paper 410](https://tp410.com/). According to [this site](https://www.cheresources.com/invision/topic/29391-hydraulic-resistance-of-tees-converging-vs-diverging-flow-crane-tp-410/), Crane's approach may be easier with constant minor coefficients as long as you know direction of the flow.